# Inequality, monotone convergence of certain Riemann sum

Tags: reference-request, inequalities

So, we managed to prove the following inequality:
Let $f$ be a *decreasing* *convex* function on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, let $p$ be a positive integer and $r\geq 0$.
Then
\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{p} \sum_{\ell=1}^{p} f\left(\frac{\ell+r}{p} \right) \leq \frac{1}{p+1} \sum_{\ell=1}^{p+1} f\left( \frac{\ell+r}{p+1} \right).
\end{align}

**Does this inequality have a name?** Is it known?

It is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3362/when-do-riemann-sums-converge-monotonically) question over at math.stackexchange.

Comment: Of course "defined on $[0,1]$" is not what you want.  The preprint says $[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: Ah, right! I edited accordingly.

Comment: It should follow from Karamata majorization inequality and monotonicity.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes, I thought so too, but note that the number of terms in the LHS is not the same as RHS. We did not manage to derive the above as a consequence.

Comment: It is the same: $p(p+1)$ terms in both sides after we multiply by $p(p+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

So, the proof is available now in [the appendix of this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.01447),
and we found a few references to the case $r=0$.